# What is the meaning of (sampling) a continuous probability distribution?

Tags: measure-theory

According to theory,  a continuous probability function is $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, such that $f$ is continuous and the  improper integral of it is $1$. Moreover the function is never negative. The concept makes sense in that these distributions can be thought of as a limit as discrete RVs are summed.

So far so good... But then the words "let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a sample from a contiuous probability distribution" are uttered. This to me sounds a bit mythical, I don't think there is any way we could sample a continuous distribution.

What actually is the appropriate meaning of such sentences?

Comment: In math we talk about a lot of things we couldn't actually physically do.  Do you object to talking about a number chosen uniformly at random from $[0,1]$, for instance?

Comment: @EricWofsey Given that we can't even define almost all numbers in that interval, yes.

Comment: OK, then you'll just have to accept that this is a mathematical idealization and not a statement about the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "appropriate meaning".  You are missing nothing.  This is not meant to have any exact real-world meaning but is instead a mathematical idealization.

The completely rigorous meaning from a purely mathematical perspective is that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are *random variables* on some probability space which are independent and have the given continuous distribution function $f$.  That is, for any $r_1,\dots,r_n\in\mathbb{R}$, the probability that $x_i<r_i$ is true for all $i=1,\dots,n$ is $\prod_{i=1}^n\int_{-\infty}^{r_i} f(x)dx$.

Comment: Could the interpretation be along the lines of: "We should be able to get as close as we would like by sampling from the sum of ever increasing amount of discrete variables".

I just think  that it's a bit weird to have mathematical theorems that does not correspond to stating a fact about any mathematical operations. Sounds like a fantasy novel or something. Although, it could be that I should move over to the Philosophy exchange.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mathematical operations".  The meaning in terms of random variables is perfectly "mathematical", by the usual meaning of the term.

Comment: Wofsey Mathematical operations as in $+,-,\cdot,\text{mod}$ etc. An example: "Consider a random sample $x_1,x_2$ from gaussian, the expectation of the sum is $E(x_1+x_2)$ ". The literal reading in terms of operations is then: "we can get as close to $E(x_1+x_2)$ as we would like by sampling and summing two samples, from the sum of $n$ discrete RVs, $m$ times and averaging". Since sampling from a continuous distribution is impossible the theorem is otherwise meaningless in terms of mathematical operations.

Comment: Sampling a discrete distribution is also impossible.  How do you propose sampling something which has _exactly_ 1/2 probability, for instance?  I really think that your concern here is wholly misplaced.

Comment: The _vast majority_ of mathematics cannot be stated solely in terms of "mathematical operations" in the way you seem to have in mind.

Comment: it is possible to sample discrete RVs. Pseudo-random numbers :)). Of course, I understand some don't have this in mind, but that to me is what the theory ultimately is about... about something rather than nothing.

When mathematics is not (at least ultimately) about operations we can check and see, it quickly becomes meaningless in a sense. I do not think meaningless is what they had in mind with probability theory. If the theory did not correspond very closely to the operations I outlined I reckon it would be dispensed with.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous probability distribution has continuous random variables. The probability density function, pdf, f(x) follows some rules.

$$ f(x) \geq 0 $$

$f(x) $ is piece wise continuous and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1 $$

Also if $X$ is a continuous random variable falling in the interval $(a,b)$

$$ Pr(a < X < b) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

Importantly

$$ Pr(X=c) = \int_{c}^{c} f(x) dx = 0 $$